# How do I adapt an interactive d3 gravity simulation to operate on localStorage items?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to adapt a stackoverflow answer (that I cannot locate now!) that linked to this: https://codepen.io/keetraxx/pen/oNzXKVN - which I did save.

I wish to make the interactive cable drawing (`.on("mouse*` methods) a single subroutine that does the drawing. However, the cable mid-point is pulled to the right instead of simulating gravity. After a bit of head-scratching and debugging, I can see that in my desired subroutine, the 3 middle nodes are not assigned `fx` and `fy` values. But I'm not sure how to fix things. Help? :D

Here is my "not working properly" js and css code: https://gist.github.com/ology/a13a274a42f5926be504f56c71b1e2aa

And here is a screenshot of the js in action: [image] where the orange cable is one drawn interactively with the `.on(mouse*` methods, and the extruded blue one is drawn with my adapted subroutine.

I tried copy-pasting the innards of the `.on("mouse*` methods to a single subroutine and firing that in a loop of localStorage cables, but the gravity simulation is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turns out to be that I was not using integers for my node coordinates. The assignment of `x0`, `y0`, `x1`, and `y1` in the `draw_patch()` function, should each be assigned **after** `parseInt()` has converted the respective `split` string parts. For example: `const x0 = parseInt(xy[0]);`